Change view of dynamic zones while adding new block in Content Manager in Strapi v4
Change view of dynamic zones while adding new block in Content Manager in Strapi v4
I need to show preview instead of existing default icons (screen #1/2). Documentation provides Admin Panel API for plugins and lots of settings such as Injection Zones API but i didn't find any information to patch this icons. If it's not possible. if this is not possible, then add functionality on top of existing blocks and show a preview of the block when hovering (i.e add my custom plugin on hover)
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to patch this whole thing through the Injection Zones API, but I did not find the place I needed where I could implement my plugin or patch the display of the dynamic zones selection in the content type manager
